# elasticsearch REST API escape sequence

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, escaping

I happened created a strange index name `osquery-mounts-%host"}` via `logstash` ruby filter code,

Now I can not delete it:

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://el:9200/osquery-mounts-%host"}'
```

It reports error

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"invalid escape sequence `%ho' at index 15 of: osquery-mounts-%host"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"invalid escape sequence `%ho' at index 15 of: osquery-mounts-%host"},"status":400}[
```

Whatever I add backslash to escape % and { }, it report similar error.

I'v also tried delete it from kibana develop tools but failed.

How can I delete the index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I figured it out.

```
curl -sSL -XDELETE 'http://el:9200/osquery-mounts-%%\{host\}'
```

Use %% to escape %, use backslash to escape { and }