# how to close a index in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have multiple indexes like 'vunet-%{tenant_id}-%{bu_id}-index-info-2020.09.01' in elasticsearch . I want to delete these indexes. But when ever I am trying to delete it by using following command

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/vunet-%{tenant_id}-%{bu_id}-index-info-2020.09.01/_close?pretty"
```

But I am getting error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "invalid escape sequence `%te' at index 6 of: vunet-%tenant_id-%bu_id-index-info-2020.09.01"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "invalid escape sequence `%te' at index 6 of: vunet-%tenant_id-%bu_id-index-info-2020.09.01"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [elasticsearch REST API escape sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506943/elasticsearch-rest-api-escape-sequence)

Comment: the `_close` endpoint doesn't delete the index, use `-X DELETE` instead on the index name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (this solves the escaping issue):

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/vunet-%%\{tenant_id\}-%%\{bu_id\}-index-info-2020.09.01/_close?pretty"
```

*Escaping Special Characters:*

Lucene supports escaping special characters that are part of the query syntax. The current list special characters are

```
+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \
```

To escape these character use the \ before the character. For example to search for `(1+1):2` use the query:

```
\(1\+1\)\:2
```

[Escaping Special Characters](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_4_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%25)

Also, take a look at [escape the %](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/3.3/escape-percent.html)